# SELinux for in-house applications

Tags: selinux

I have a ruby application running on Puma, behind nginx. I want to use SELinux to mitigate the risk of it being used as an entry point to the rest of our system.
I couldn't find any reference of sysadmins doing that for in-house applications (creating new SELinux labels, rules etc), only utilizing repo-provided SELinux labels.
Am I taking the wrong approach, or did I miss something?

Comment: You can run it under `httpd_t` (easy) or create your own policy (time consuming).

Comment: running it under `http_d` actually sounds like a good idea. @MichaelHampton do you know if people are actually doing it?

Comment: I do it for apps written in RoR, Node.js, PHP...